# nodejs - req.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I want to post some data to server. The problem is that, it seems the server cannot receive the data.

So my post data is like this:

```
name=hello&email=there&message=sometext
```

and my server code is like this:

```
var url  = require('url'),
    express = require('express'),
    http=require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);


app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(req, response){

    console.log(req.body);
    // console.log(request.body.name);

});

server.listen(4000);
console.log('server running ' + 'now ' + Date.now());
```

when the `console.log(reg.body)` run, the terminal output is "undefined"

Comment: `name=hello&email=there&message=sometext` seems `GET` data to me. You should send them in `form` or `params` in **AJAX POST**

Comment: it was ajax post, have a look at this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/joacijxke8pyfox/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-18%20at%208.18.25%20PM.png

Comment: Which version of express are you using? You could also try to log the entire `req` object, that will most likely show enough information that you can answer your question yourself;)

Comment: Try to move `app.use(express.bodyParser()));` ahead of `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: inspiredJW, you are right, change the order of the code will work. Why don't u make it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move app.use(express.bodyParser())); ahead of app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Answer (score 4):

All query strings output are parsed by default by `app.use(express.bodyParser());`.. simple solution to your problem is try logging  `req.query` , something like

```
console.log(req.query);
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it solves your problem. even if it is an outdated question.

Comment: Used the way you said in your answer has been deprecated in Express 4. I found this answer helpful, but the proper way to use `bodyParser` is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install body-parser. The current version of Express has a built-in body parser.
If installed, you can use:

```
app.use(express.json())
```