# bodyParser is deprecated express 4

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am using express 4.0 and I'm aware that body parser has been taken out of the express core, I am using the recommended replacement, however I am getting

`body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares server.js:15:12
body-parser deprecated urlencoded: explicitly specify "extended: true" for extended parsing node_modules/body-parser/index.js:74:29`

Where do I find this supposed middlewares? or should I not be getting this error?

```
var express     = require('express');
var server      = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var passport    = require('./config/passport');
var routes      = require('./routes');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
});

server.set('view engine', 'jade');
server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

server.use(bodyParser()); 
server.use(passport.initialize());

// Application Level Routes
routes(server, passport);

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Note for future readers, OP's script uses ```var server = express()```, but when reading (seemingly ALL of) the answers below, assume that the line ```var app = express()``` was used.

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

It means that using the `bodyParser()` **constructor** has been [deprecated](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900),  as of 2014-06-19.

```
app.use(bodyParser()); //Now deprecated
```

You now need to call the methods separately

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And so on.

If you're still getting a warning with `urlencoded` you need to use

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

The `extended` config object key now needs to be explicitly passed, since it now has no default value.

If you are using Express >= 4.16.0, body parser has been re-added under the methods `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`.

Comment: I have the same warning after updating `body-parser` to `1.4.3` and `express` to `4.4.4`. The line that gives the warning: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());`

Comment: is it still safe to use bodyParser ?

Comment: @eslammostafa You can use bodyparser, you just can't call the constructor. You need to call each individual method.

Comment: @BenFortune thanks Ben, i got it, i was just worried the /tmp thing, but now i checked again, the /tmp problem happens only if we used bodyParser to parse multipart forms, http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html i will use formidable then for multipart forms.

Comment: Multipart should only be used when you have file input elements in your form, which bodyparser doesn't support since it doesn't support file uploads.

Comment: Works as of July 2014 on latest builds of node, express and bodyparser.

Comment: What does `extended` do?

Comment: `extended - parse extended syntax with the qs module. (default: true)`, though they've deprecated the default option.

Comment: Sucks that I don't see anything in the docs about using `extended: true`

Comment: an explanation of the difference would be helpful. I also see below that you can just use both. But why? What considerations should you make?

Comment: They need to stop changing this for little reason, it's bloody annoying

Comment: The best way I explain extended true is that not using extended means that 

`curl --data "user[email]=foo&user[password]=bar" localhost:3000/login`

 would be received by the server in `req.body` as `{ user[email]: "foo", ...}` whereas `req.body` would be `{user: {email: "foo", ... }}` with `extended: true`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for breaking it down.  Got rid of all those dumb deprecated warnings.  All my my form data is coming through!

Comment: Would someone kindly explain, whether you would still include the statement `app.use(bodyParser.json())` even after you make `extended: true`. So basically would `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})` still need you to have `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.. or would this statement only be required if `extended: false`?

Comment: They're not really related. If you're going to be parsing forms you'll need `bodyParser.urlencoded`, if you have multidimensional forms then you'll want `extended: true` with that. If you're going to be parsing JSON then you need `bodyParser.json`.

Comment: @BenFortune how do i use express.json()/urlencoded() i tried it but if i return req.json({data: req.body}) i get  {} in postman

Comment: @MayankSingh Exactly the same way you'd use `bodyParser.json/urlencoded`.

Comment: @BenFortune I am using it like app.use(express.json()) and it is returning empty object, Just to be clear since i am using express.json i dont need to bodyparser explicitely since it is using it under the hood?

Comment: @BenFortune nvm for somereason express is not taking form-data from postman only xxx-encoded and raw, thank you anyway.

Comment: @CamiloMartin

The `extended` option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the `querystring` library (when `false`) or the `qs` library (when `true`).

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/tree/1.19.0#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

Comment: bodyParser itself is now marked as deprecated and is available as part of express, see Sridhar's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892173/196869, `express.json()`

Comment: @BenFortune Can you please update the answer for 2020?

Comment: this doesn't work in the latest version, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4/59892173#59892173)

Answer (score 463):

Want **zero warnings**? Use it like this:

```
// Express v4.16.0 and higher
// --------------------------
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// For Express version less than 4.16.0
// ------------------------------------
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

**Explanation**: The default value of the `extended` option has been deprecated, meaning you need to explicitly pass true or false value.

**Note for Express 4.16.0 and higher**: body parser has been re-added to provide request body parsing support out-of-the-box.

Comment: I use this, still getting the "body-parser deprecated" message. `app.use(bodyParser.json()).use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: That's right, I get a deprecation warning accessing the constructor. It is included in Express 4.17 as a dependency): https://nodejs.dev/learn/get-http-request-body-data-using-nodejs

Comment: Thanks this work's for me, but i have a question! So, now we don't need to install body-parser?

Comment: Still deprecated at express@4.17.1

Comment: With express 4.16+ body-parser is need no longer be installed or used hence the deprecation warning. express no directly contains json and urlencoded middle ware.

Answer (score 233):

**If you're using express > `4.16`, you can use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`**

> The `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` middleware have been added to provide request body parsing support out-of-the-box. This uses the [`expressjs/body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) module module underneath, so apps that are currently requiring the module separately can switch to the built-in parsers.

**Source** [Express 4.16.0 - Release date: 2017-09-28](https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0)

With this,

```
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

becomes,

```
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: Means we don't need to install body parser anymore??

Comment: yeah. we dont it as seperate package, since it is now available as a part of express.

Comment: im getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 6
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 80):

## Don't use body-parser

If you are using Express 4.16+ You can do it just like this with **express**:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

You can now uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**To get the POST content, you can use `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or if this doesn't work

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 43):

Even I faced the same issue. The below change I mentioned resolved my problem.

If you're using **Express 4.16+** version, then

- You may have added a line to your code that looks like the following:

```js
app.use(bodyparser.json()); //utilizes the body-parser package
```

- You can now replace the above line with:

```js
app.use(express.json()); //Used to parse JSON bodies
```

This should not introduce any breaking changes into your applications since the code in **express.json() is based on bodyparser.json().**

- If you also have the following code in your environment:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

- You can replace the above line with:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

- If you're getting a warning saying that you still need to pass `extended` to `express.urlencoded()` then, do update the above code as:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

**A final note of caution:**

**You might not need to install the additional body-parser package to your application if you are using Express 4.16+. There are many tutorials that include the installation of body-parser because they are dated prior to the release of Express 4.16.**

Comment: It's interesting because underneath `express.json()` use the same deprecated  `body-parse.json()`

Comment: Yeah! But somehow the `express.JS` development team has simplified the json parsing strategy / configuration by just replacing one line of code with the other which syntactically doesn't make much a difference.

Comment: My console says I still have to pass `extended` to `express.urlencoded({extended: true})` using express 4.17.1

Comment: @Hache_raw I'm not sure but I guess that depends if you have somehow made the use of **UTF-8 encoding** or perhaps, it is indeed now changed. It'd be better if you refer to this [express.js urlencoding link doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) .

Answer (score 17):

In older versions of express, we had to use:

```
app.use(express.bodyparser());
```

because body-parser was a middleware between node and 
express. Now we have to use it like:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: I think you wanted to say "body-parser was middleware " ? express is not middleware as I understand

Answer (score 9):

> body-parser is a piece of express middleware that 
>          reads a form's input and stores it as a javascript
>           object accessible through `req.body` 
>         'body-parser' must be installed (via `npm install --save body-parser`) For more info see: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

When `extended` is set to true, then deflated (compressed) bodies will be inflated; when `extended` is set to false, deflated bodies are rejected.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `bodyParser.json()`, simply use `express.json()`,
You don't want to install `body-parser`

For an instance,

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that while adding

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

helps, sometimes it's a matter of your querying that determines how express handles it.

For instance, it could be that your parameters are passed in the **URL** rather than in the body

In such a case, you need to capture both the **body** and **url** parameters and use whichever is available (with preference for the body parameters in the case below)

```
app.route('/echo')
    .all((req,res)=>{
        let pars = (Object.keys(req.body).length > 0)?req.body:req.query;
        res.send(pars);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your opinion to use express-generator it will generate skeleton project to start with, `without deprecated messages` appeared in your log

run this command

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

Now, create new Express.js starter application by type this command in `your Node projects folder`.

```
express node-express-app
```

That command tell express to generate new Node.js application with the name `node-express-app`.

then `Go to the newly created project directory`, `install npm packages` and `start the app` using the command

```
cd node-express-app && npm install && npm start
```

Comment: Will this help?

Answer (score 1):

**body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5**

**express deprecated req.host: Use req.hostname instead node_modules\body-parser\index.js:100:29**

**body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules\body-parser\index.js:105:29**

No need to update express or body-parser

These errors will be removed. Follow these steps :-

1. app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // This will help in encoding.
2. app.use(bodyParser.json()); // this will support json format

It will run.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer
[Stripe webhook error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816184/stripe-webhook-error-no-signatures-found-matching-the-expected-signature-for-pa/56834675)

```js
// Use JSON parser for all non-webhook routes
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
    next();
  } else {
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
});

// Stripe requires the raw body to construct the event
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, webhookSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    // On error, log and return the error message
    console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Successfully constructed event
  console.log('✅ Success:', event.id);

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({received: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was typescript + vs code marking it wrongly as deprecated:
[image]

But if you check the source code:

```js
/** @deprecated */
declare function bodyParser(
    options?: bodyParser.OptionsJson & bodyParser.OptionsText & bodyParser.OptionsUrlencoded,
): NextHandleFunction;

declare namespace bodyParser {
```

you see it should be the constructor, not the namespace.
So either typescript or vs code is getting it wrong.
All good, there's no deprecation happening in this case (`bodyParser` as namespace=