# If node module `body-parser` is not safe, what is the next solution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read a post on `body-parser` in node.js and it claimed that it is not safe.

If I'm not to use any `body-parser` middleware in my project, what solution should I use to ensure safety?

[Do Not Use bodyParser with Express.js](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html)

[body-parser deprecation message](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900)

I'm a newbie on node.js so if your solution is provided with examples, I'll really appreciate!

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is provided in the very article you linked to.

> ### Avoid bodyParser and explicitly use the middleware that you need
>
> If you want to parse json in your endpoint, use `express.json()` middleware. If you want json and urlencoded endpoint, use `[express.json(), express.urlencoded()]` for your middleware.
>
> If you want users to upload files to your endpoint, you could use `express.multipart()` and be sure to clean up all the temp files that are created. This would still stuffer [sic] from problem #3 previously mentioned.

Note however that in Express 4, these middlewares are no longer packaged with Express. They are now available via the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) package, with `json` and `urlencoded` properties. They recommend some other packages for multipart uploads.

Comment: What are the recommended packaged?? :P

Comment: I said in my post, `body-parser` package, and enable `json` and `urlencoded` as needed.

Comment: Quoted: `They recommend some other packages for multipart uploads`. I mean this one. I'm not to use body-parser anymore because of unsafety. :P

Comment: Check the link. They have a bunch of links at the very beginning of the readme.

Comment: I found this helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Answer (score -1):

I'm using https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy

But there are several other libraries that do the same thing, so there is no definitive answer to this question.