# NodeJS and Express : How to print all the parameters passed in GET and POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I want to log all the query parameters which are passed to my endpoint. whenever they call me ie through GET , POST. i am able to print all the GET query params but struggling with POST params.

i used **req.body** but that doesnt work it just prints **[Object object]** even JSON.stringify didnt help.

Can any one point me to right source to look for it

Comment: are you using body-parser? https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser

Comment: Have you tried using `var util = require('util'); util.inspect(req.body)`?

Comment: have tried both but it didnt work

Comment: Note if none of the above comments nor my answer solve your problem, you MUST post a code snippet. We are not mind readers. Your problem is almost certainly trivial but don't make us guess what it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So POST parameters arrive in the HTTP request body, and this is handled as a stream of data chunks by node.js. So the first thing you must do is make sure you assemble the stream of chunks into a complete piece of data. Then you may want to parse it as either url encoded or JSON if that's what it is. The standard middleware for this is [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). You set it up like they say in the README:

```
const express    = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }))

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // populated!
  next()
})
```

Comment: bodyParser is deprecated: 
Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Comment: I'm not using the deprecated constructor in this code. From a quick scan the snippet still looks fine to me. If you find something deprecated please provide more detail as to what. This answer is seven years old so it's not exactly fresh in my mind.