# Does everyauth or passport works in expressJs 4+

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, everyauth

I've been looking for authentication in nodeJs. I've looked at PassportJs and Everyauth. Both of them had old documentation and old version of express used. Things that depreciated in express 4+.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4) question, which had nice answers. But had no success implementing them on PassportJs or Everyauth. So does anyone know an method to implement this ? or can anyone give me an authentication tutorial for express 4+ nodeJs authentication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work like this:

```
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    express      = require('express'),
    session      = require('express-session'),
    passport     = require('passport');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secrit cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

Scotch.io has updated its tutorial series "Easy node authentication" :

These are the changes regarding **passport** :

• [Easy node authentication with ExpressJS 4.0](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/upgrading-our-easy-node-authentication-series-to-expressjs-4-0)