# mongoose schema clarification

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to mongoose and I was trying a few basic things with express. The data isn't being retrieved in the format of the schema. It includes the id and another value not the first name or the last name. The post seems to work fine. Can anyone help me out in this?

```
var entrySchema = new Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String
});

var Entry = mongoose.model('Entry', entrySchema);

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/",function(req,res,next){

    Entry.find(function(err,entries){   
        if(err)
            {
                res.send(err);
            }

        res.send(entries);
    })


})

router.post("/",function(req,res){
    var entry = new Entry();
    entry.firstname = req.body.firstname;
    entry.lastname = req.body.lastname;

    entry.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.send({message: "success"});
    });
})
```

Comment: Can you show us what is being returned?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed to define Schema as `mongoose.Schema` like -

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var entrySchema = new Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String
});
```

Comment: i have the first line in the code. Sorry i missed to add it. it isn't working with that

Comment: @user3428217 can you console `req.body.firstname` and check whether its coming or not ?

Comment: they both are undefined and i checked the below URL and changed accordingly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4 But still the vars are undefined

Comment: @user3428217 Check the content-type..try by setting headers as  `Content-Type: application/json` while hitting the api..and let me know then.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. The problem was solved with multer node dependency as suggested in https://github.com/expressjs/multer