# node express bodyparser deprecated, new syntax does not work

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to write a simple html page that upon a button click, send a value from a text input field to node server, which then prints on the console of the entered value. know that with express 4 the previous bodyparser is deprecated and following the discussion here: [bodyParser is deprecated express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4)

But with the following code I still get errors when starting the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/java_preview', function (req, res) {

   console.log("Request for java_preivew:");
   console.log(req.body.url);
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started...")
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#previewButton').click(function () {
            //var enterURL=$('inputUrl').val();
            //alert("Button Clicked:"+$('#inputUrl').val());
            $.post("java_preview", {url: $('#inputUrl').val()} );
        });

      });
```

error log:

```
/Users/-/Google Drive/papers/ISWC2016_demo/webpages/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99
      throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundle
            ^
Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/Users/-/Google Drive/papers/ISWC2016_demo/webpages/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/-/Google Drive/papers/ISWC2016_demo/webpages/startserver.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

any suggestions please

Comment: Have you read the error log? It's telling you exactly what to do.

Comment: sorry i could be missing some basics here, but I do not understand. Do you mean it is related to where 'express' is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bodyParser is not a part of express anymore. Install it as a dependency with npm, and include it in your project.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the `body-parser` package needs to be installed separately :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed the word `express` from here:

```
app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

And everything should work :)

Comment: thank you, if you mean 'app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded())' then it creates a new error: ReferenceError: bodyParser is not defined

Comment: You need to include it at the beginning of the file :) `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` no inclusion, no fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

The same answer that you  are referring say that you have to use **extended: true**

```
If you're still getting a warning with urlencoded you need to use

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
The extended config object key now needs to be explicitly passed, 
since it now has no default value.
```