# How to use body-parser in express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a post api that has object but i am not able to print in console its throowing undefined i thought i am missing body-parser but after adding body parser i see error `body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares` Any help will be appreciated.

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Diagram = require('./api/diagram/diagram.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/saveUpdateDiagram',bodyParser,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var route = require('./server/routes').router;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB connected ');
});


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', route);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.listen(8760, function() {
    console.log('I am listening 8760...');
});
```

Comment: Try taking the `bodyParser` you are passing into the route out.  Since you are using the bodyParser at the server level (via `app.use(...)`) you already have the middleware loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use of body-parser in app.js is fine. It is middleware, and it is loaded with app.use so that it will be applied to every incoming request.

You can remove it in routes.js, so that it looks like so:`

```js
var express = require('express');
var Diagram = require('./api/diagram/diagram.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/saveUpdateDiagram', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

`
Also, try replacing:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
```

with:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: i removed body-parser from routes.js ,but i am still getting undefined printed in console no idea why

Comment: See if setting extended to true works, per the example in my edits.

Comment: i removed body-parser from app and added to router and used same as app `router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))' it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Your use of body-parser in app.js is fine. It is middleware, and it is loaded with app.use but the  **problem is the position where you used the app.use('/', route); it should be placed below** the app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

Comment: This was my issue.

Comment: Man, i just put that line above to cleanup my code and i was banging my head from last hour to know why it is not working when it was just working fine a minute! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

It means that using the `bodyParser()` constructor has been deprecated, as of 2014-06-19.

```
 app.use(bodyParser()); //Now deprecated You now need to call the methods separately
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

 app.use(bodyParser.json()); //And so on.
```

If you're still getting a warning with urlencoded you need to use

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
 }))
```

The extended config object key now needs to be explicitly passed, since it now has no default value, as said [over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4/24330353#24330353)

Comment: I am calling method separately in app.js

Answer (score 0):

Simple method,
Install body-parser using following command

```
npm install -g body-parser
```

Then require it in your application using

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

then you can use it in your app adding following line of code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: body parser is now built in.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not working by just adding to the app so I had to

```
router.post('/api/insertorupdaterecord_Scenario/:tableName',bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) =>
```

Also when I just tried

```
router.post('/api/insertorupdaterecord_Scenario/:tableName',bodyParser, async (req, res) =>
```

got below error

```
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules\body-parser\index.js:104:29
```

Comment: this section is reserved for submitting an answer. You can post your comments against any answer that you tried but didn't help so that the author of that answer can improve the answer in the light of your feedback. Welcome to the stackoverflow anyway. Happy posting!