# Body Parser Deprecated

Tags: express, body-parser

I am currently learning node and express. But when I require and use body-parser my code editor(VS Code) says that it is deprecated. How do I work with this? I will link the image of my editor.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bodyParser is deprecated express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4)

Comment: Actually I tried to search for this earlier. I found this answer but it didn't helped me.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892173/2436655)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Body parser is now added to Express. You can use it like the following:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

You can add this middleware to the code which will then be able to use json methods.

Answer (score 35):

If you facing 'bodyParser' is deprecated.

**Just do**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.json());
```

**Note:** If you are using `4.16.0` or `later` express version.

Answer (score 11):

body parser package is deprecated. If you are using latest version of express you don't have to install body-parser package.

You can directly use

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use body-parser

Body parsing is now builtin with `express` So, simply do

```
app.use(express.json()) //For JSON requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

directly from express

You can uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**Then you can get the POST content of the request using `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or like this, for string JSON body

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```