# NuxtJS2: Body-parser is deprecated when used in a Nuxt module

Tags: nuxt.js, body-parser

I have a Nuxt module that looks like so:

```
import { createHash } from 'crypto'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

export default function () {
  const config = this.options.privateRuntimeConfig.cloudinary

  this.nuxt.hook('render:setupMiddleware', (app) => {
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use('/api/cloudinary/signature', setSignature)
  })

  function setSignature(req, res) {
    try {
      const sha1 = createHash('sha1')
....etc...
```

In VSCODE, I am getting the following error that bodyparser is *deprecated*:

[image]

However, the app works fine.  But if I remove it, it doesn't. So, is it safe to keep it or should I replace body-parser with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good. As `body-parser` is commonly used within express apps, VS Code shows it as deprecated as you can use `express.json` instead (see [bodyParser is deprecated express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4/59892173#59892173)). As you don't wanna pull in express, just keep it as is