# Express.js "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" in req.body

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

`

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username)
    console.log(req.body.password)
    
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

```
<body>
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <label for="username">

        </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
        <label for="password">
            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
```

`

I just started learning express but already have a problem and I can't find any fixes. Somehow the req.body variable is undefined in the post. This is going to be a login system. (Sorry for my bad english)

I first tried to do it like here on github: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/express-crash-course but i still had the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" error in my console. So I was looking for something else and found this: https://codeshack.io/basic-login-system-nodejs-express-mysql/
My code is based on the codeshack example but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Have you added this line at start of your app? `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

Comment: [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/express-simple-rtqvks?file=pages%2Findex.html,index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access body of post request, we need to use express middleware which will parse the body of request and it will attached it under `req.body` object.
In order to do it we can use `express.urlencoded()` middleware.
for more information [link](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded)

```
router.post("/login",express.urlencoded({ extended: true }) , (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username)
    console.log(req.body.password)
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add middleware before your handlers

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

Comment: `bodyParser` is deprecated

Comment: Only the constructor is deprecated, which he is not using. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24330353/7075674